# Ruby gem visibility in rails application

Tags: ruby

I have created simple gem called `gotqn_first_gem` and in my `gotqn_first_gem.rb` file I have the following code:

```
require "gotqn_first_gem/version"

module GotqnFirstGem
  class Test

    def initialize(parameters = {})
      @url = 'Hello World'
    end

    #
    def to_s
      "<p>#{@url}<p/>"
    end

  end
end
```

I have successfully push it in the [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/) and installed in in demo rails application adding `gem 'gotqn_first_gem'` in my `GemFile` and running `bundle install`.

In a helper `.rb` file I have added `require 'gotqn_first_gem'` but running the following code `are = Test.new` give me error:

```
uninitialized constant AlbumsHelper::Image::Test
```

Could anyone tell how successfully to require and use gem code and why the gem code is not visible in the whole application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test` doesn’t exist, `GotqnFirstGem::Test` does. So you need to do:

```
GotqnFirstGem::Test.new
```

instead.